# Launch Spark in Foreground via Supervisor

Tags: fork, supervisord

We have a spark cluster that launches via supervisor.  Excerpts:

```
/etc/supervisor/conf.d/spark_master.conf:
command=./sbin/start-master.sh
directory=/opt/spark-1.4.1

/etc/supervisor/conf.d/spark_worker.conf:
command=./sbin/start-slave.sh spark://spark-master:7077
directory=/opt/spark-1.4.1
```

The challenge for supervisor is these scripts launch a daemon process and detach, where supervisor expects things to run in foreground without a fork.  So far, my efforts to convince supervisor that forking is okay or to convince spark not to fork have come to naught.  Anyone find a better way?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution I inferred from [a previous version of the documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/spark-standalone.html):

```
/etc/supervisor/conf.d/spark_master.conf:
command=/opt/spark-1.4.1/bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master
directory=/opt/spark-1.4.1

/etc/supervisor/conf.d/spark_worker.conf:
command=/opt/spark-1.4.1/bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://spark-master:7077
directory=/opt/spark-1.4.1
```

Launching via the `bin/spark-class` command stays in the foreground, and has the added satisfaction of not perpetuating the "slave" terminology.

Answer (score 2):

As of Spark 2.1 (and [this commit](https://github.com/apache/spark/commit/c2c107abad8b462218d33c70b946e840663228a1)) it is possible to set the environment variable `SPARK_NO_DAEMONIZE` and have supervisor invoke the provided start scripts `$SPARK_HOME/sbin/start-master.sh` and `$SPARK_HOME/sbin/start-slave.sh` directly.

This is documented in `$SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-env.sh.template` and `$SPARK_HOME/sbin/spark-daemon.sh`